# Force project AND solution upgrade from VS2010 to VS2013, not just solution file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, devenv

I'm trying to upgrade solutions to Visual Studio 2013 and target .NET 4.5.

I understand that targeting .NET 4.5 is as easy as right clicking on each project in each solution and changing them to 4.5.  But I also want our solutions to open **by default** in VS 2013, even if someone has other versions on their machine.  I also don't want to do this for every project in every solution we have.

Things I've tried:

- Deleting my .suo file for each solution that I want to upgrade, then opening them in VS2013 so that it asks me to update my solution. (It doesn't ask)
- Running `devenv.exe "C:\my-solution.sln" /upgrade`. All it does is say:

> This project/solution does not require migration.  It will open
>   without modification.

Is there any way to force an update of all solutions/projects to Visual Studio 2013?

EDIT: @SLaks comment works for .sln files but I still have many .csproj files in that solution that are themselves opening with a different version of Visual Studio.  Also it would be nice if there were a solution that didn't require me to open every solution file in notepad and change one character.

Comment: Open the `.sln` file in a text editor and change the first line.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio opens a project and what the project file is targetted for ar very different things

Comment: @GrantWinney this only really solves part of my problem.  If I go directly to the project file and open it, it still opens in Visual Studio 2010 (or 2012, depending on which one it is), even though it's in a solution that's opening in 2013.

Comment: @SLaks again this only solves one problem, I still have multiple project files that open with different versions.